# How to send money from europe to usa EUR - USD?

Tags: currency, money-transfer, eur-euro, usd-us-dollar

What's the best way for transferring money from Europe to the USA and vice-versa?

By *best* I mean lowest fees and a good exchange rate. To the best of my knowledge banks are usually bad with both. I found several services doing research online but I was wondering if I should "trust" them or not.

Comment: It depends at lot on the amount your talking about - a lot of currency transfer services require a minimum amount of money to be sent.

Comment: @TimoGeusch let's say about 2-3k (EUR or USD)

Comment: There is always the low-tech way: http://money.stackexchange.com/a/5859/1229

Answer (score 1):

The website http://currencyfair.com/ provides a service which gives you both a decent exchange rate (about 1% off from mid-market rate) and a moderately low fee for the transfer: 4 USD for outgoing ACH in the US, 10 USD for same-day US wire. For the reverse (sending money from the US to EU) the fees are: 3 EUR for an ACH, 8 EUR for a same-day EUR wire.

It has been online for quite a while, so I assume its legit, but I'd do a transfer for a smaller sum first, to see if there are any problems, and then a second transfer for the whole sum.

Comment: thanks! did you ever use this service? How did you like it?

Comment: @Gevorg I registered buy didn't use them yet, as TransferWise.com provides cheaper rates between the Eurozone and UK. To register you need to upload a scan of your ID and scans of two different documents showing your address - these can be bank statements or utility bills.

Comment: An alternative to Transferwise.com is TransferGo.com

Answer (score 0):

PayPal.

Or even Western Union or MoneyGram.  Despite their fees, there is a reason those companies are still in business.